# Find available dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two tables (1. orders and 2. cars):

**Cars**

[image: Cars]

**Orders**

[image: Orders]

I'm trying to find all cars that are available at a given date. In this case I want to find all available cars between 2016-05-03 and 2016-05-05. I check for cars that are `NOT BETWEEN` said date or cars that have not been registered in an order yet (`orders.car_id IS NULL`). Here is the query:

```
SELECT destination, COUNT(destination) AS 'available cars' 
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN orders ON cars.id = orders.car_id

WHERE (orders.car_id IS NULL

OR (

  date_to NOT BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05' 
  AND date_from NOT BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05'

  )

) 

AND destination = 'Kristiansand' GROUP BY destination
```

The problem is with the **Audi A1 with id = 8**. As you can see, it is registered on two appointments, one from `2016-05-03` to `2016-05-05` and one from `2016-04-29` to `2016-04-30`.

Since the second pair of dates at the end of April are `NOT BETWEEN` the given dates in the query, the A1 is an available car which is far from true.

> I'm trying to fetch all cars available for rental outside of the given
>   dates in Kristiansand.

Comment: What is your question? What are you actually trying to achieve? It's a bit unclear to me.

Comment: @ConsiderMe I'm trying to fetch all cars available for rental outside of the given dates in Kristiansand.

Comment: which table is 'destination' field from?

Comment: @TinTran It's in the Cars table, sorry. I've left out some of the columns because I had to translate my query and tables to English before asking my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 periods T1 and T2 to check to see if they overlap
you do this check (T1.start <= T2.end) AND (T1.end >= T2.start).

so try this below query, (it checks and makes sure that there doesn't exist an order of the same car that overlap the specified period

```
SET @startdate = '2016-05-03',@enddate = '2016-05-05';

SELECT c.destination,COUNT(c.destination) as available_cars
FROM cars c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM orders o
                  WHERE o.car_id = c.id
                  AND o.date_from <= @enddate
                  AND o.date_to >= @startdate)
AND c.destination = 'Kristiansand'
GROUP BY c.destination
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9340e3/4

You can remove the SET statement and hardcode in your @enddate and @startdate

Comment: That worked! It only returned the Volvo S80 which has not been affiliated with any order yet. The A1 was excluded. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change your thinking from exclusionary:

```
  date_to NOT BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05' 
  AND date_from NOT BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05'
```

to inclusionary:

```
  (date_from < '2016-05-03' AND date_to < '2016-05-05') OR
  (date_from > '2016-05-03' AND date_to > '2016-05-05')
```

Comment: That query returned [this](https://i.gyazo.com/ba8f69a223c23f5b98695328168c9093.png). It's still not right, though. The Audi A1 is not supposed to show up at all because it's not available between 2016-05-03 and 2016-05-05. **I changed the SELECT to cars.id, brand, mode, date_from, date_to**.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to find which cars are not available and then exclude them from the list. Something like this:

```
SELECT destination, COUNT(destination) AS 'available cars'
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN orders ON cars.id = orders.car_id 
        AND (date_to BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05' 
        OR date_from BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05')

WHERE orders.car_id IS NULL
    AND destination = 'Kristiansand' GROUP BY destination
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, because of join you have **theoretically you have 2 different AUDIs** in the result set. I can suggest to use `BETWEEN` instead of `NOT BETWEEN`, get the ordered cars, and exclude them from cars table using statement `NOT IN` with subquery, example below.

```
SELECT destination, COUNT(destination) AS 'available cars' 
FROM cars 
WHERE cars.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT car_id FROM orders WHERE 
    date_to BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05' 
    AND date_from BETWEEN '2016-05-03' AND '2016-05-05'
)
```

NOTE: This query not tested, we can do it if you provide SQLFiddle or something like that.

P.S. There are more optimal ways to do the same, with `NOT EXISTS` statement or you can use `JOIN` with subquery.